# Where is the missing bracket in my script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on a main menu for a game I am making in unity, Im trying to make a new/load game system, since this game is 2D, I think it should just save your current level in a playerpref, and there is an array with the variables in order, but I only have a test level, I cannot find the missing bracket, and it also gives me a CS1022 "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected", I think the missing bracket is the reason, please help, Im fairly new to CSharp.

My Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenuHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (not(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("currentlevel"))) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("currentlevel", 1);
        }

        public string[] levels = new string[1];
        public string[] levels = new string[]{"Test"}; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    //public void NewGame {
    //
    //}
}
```

Comment: The error is because you try declare public  array mid start method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your code should look:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MainMenuHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] levels = new string[1];
    public string[] levelsTest = new string[] { "Test" };
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (!(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("currentlevel")))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("currentlevel", 1);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So was my problem the fact that I used 'not' instead of '!'? I used to work with Python, so I guess that 'not' isn't a valid function.

Comment: well, not is not valid, and you certainly have variables with the same name and some brackets out of position ^^'